# Using '>' Inside .innerHTML Causes Premature Closing Of HTML Statement

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I'm currently trying to return a button inside inner.HTML while using React.  Here's the line of code in question:

```js
document.getElementById("groupDisplay").innerHTML = "Group Name: "+doc.id+" Module Code: "+doc.data().ModuleCode+' <input type="button" value="Join Group" onClick={ ()=>joinGroup()}>';
```

`groupDisplay` is just an empty div element, and  `doc.id` and `doc.data().ModuleCode` are values that return correctly

The problem is with the `"onClick={ ()=>joinGroup()}"` as the `>` symbol before `joinGroup()` is closing the button tag early.  This only happens when I'm using `.innerHTML`. When I'm editing normal HTML it works fine.

Full code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { compose } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signout } from "../store/actions/auth";
import requireAuth from "./hoc/requireAuth";
import firebase from "../services/firebase.js";


var db = firebase.firestore();

const Main = ({ signout }) => {
  return (
    <div id="homePage" className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div class="col s6" id="createPage">
              <form id="createGroup">
            <i className="large material-icons prefix search-icon">group_add</i>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col s12">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s12 vert-align">
                          <input type="text" id="cgroupName" name="groupName"/>
                    <label htmlFor="cgroupName">Group Name</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="input-field col s12 vert-align">
                    <input type="text" id="cgroupModuleCode" name="moduleCode"/>
                    <label htmlFor="cgroupModuleCode">Module Code</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                  <button onClick={ ()=> createGroup()}>Create Group</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              </form>
          </div>

        <div className="col s6">
          {/*<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>*/}
          {/* Renders the search bar */}
          <i className="large material-icons prefix search-icon">group</i>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col s12">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="input-field col s12 vert-align">
                  <i className="material-icons prefix search-icon">search</i>
                  <input type= "text" id ="groupSearch" name="searchGroup"/>
                  <label htmlFor="groupSearch">Search For A Group</label>
                  <a className="waves-effect waves-teal btn-flat search-btn" onClick={ ()=> searchGroups()}>Search</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* Display any searched groups here */}
          <div class="row" id="groupDisplay">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button onClick={ () => profile()} hidden>Profile</button>
      <button className="btn-switch" onClick={() => signout()}>Log Out</button>
    </div>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.firebaseReducer.auth
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    signout: () => dispatch(signout())
  };
}

// function buildGroup(){
//  document.getElementById("homePage").style.display = "none";
//  document.getElementById("createPage").style.display = "block";
// }

function profile(){

}

// function back(){
//  document.getElementById("homePage").style.display = "block";
//  document.getElementById("createPage").style.display = "none";
// }

function logOut(){
  document.getElementById("navbar").style.display = "none";
  signout();
}

function searchGroups(){
    if(document.getElementById("groupSearch").value == ""){
        document.getElementById("groupDisplay").innerHTML = "Please enter a value and try again.";
    }
    else{
        let GroupCollection = db.collection('groups').doc(document.getElementById("groupSearch").value);
        GroupCollection.get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              document.getElementById("groupDisplay").innerHTML = "No Results.";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("groupDisplay").innerHTML = "Group Name: "+doc.id+" Module Code: "+doc.data().ModuleCode+' <input type="button" value="Join Group" onClick={ ()=>joinGroup()}>';
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            document.getElementById("groupDisplay").innerHTML = "Error getting document: "+err;
          });
    }
}

function createGroup(){
        const GroupCollection = db.collection('groups');
        GroupCollection.doc(document.getElementById("cgroupName").value).set({
        ModuleCode:document.getElementById("cgroupModuleCode").value,
        Timetable: "",
        User0: "",
        User1: "",
        User2: "",
        User3: "",
        User4: "",
        User5: "",
        User6: "",
        User7: "",
        User8: "",
        User9: "",
    })
}

function joinGroup(){
    alert("Hello");
    console.log('Button');
}

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  ),
  requireAuth
)(Main);
```

Comment: Please format your post for better reading. Post the full HTML/Js in a snippet please.

Answer (score 1):

JS normally won't break with this simple `=>` but since your are putting this whole onClick inside quotes `"` it would understand as string. In that case, try to encode sensitive symbols such as `>` into `&gt;`

Best is not using arrow function `{()=>joinGroup()}` at all but change into `{this.joinGroup}`

For a safer method, create the input in JS instead

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute('type', 'button');
input.setAttribute('value', 'Join group');
input.onClick = () => joinGroup();

document.getElementById("groupDisplay").appendChild(input);
```

Comment: We've tried changing it into {this.joinGroup} it won't run the joinGroup() function as this button isn't in a class.

Comment: Could you post the whole JS and HTML or create a snippet?

Comment: Whole JS file posted.

Comment: Like suggested, changing to `&gt;` will help escape that character but it's unlikely that the function `joinGroup` will be executed due to function scoping and throw a "Undefined function joinGroup" in the global scope instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks for a template literal (will escape almost everything)

```
document.getElementById("groupDisplay").innerHTML = "Group Name: "+doc.id+" Module Code: "+doc.data().ModuleCode+ `<input type="button" value="Join Group" onClick={ ()=>joinGroup()}>`;
```

or better yet:

```
document.getElementById("groupDisplay").innerHTML = `Group Name: ${doc.id} Module Code: ${doc.data().ModuleCode}<input type="button" value="Join Group" onClick={joinGroup}>`;
```

(Use point free style in your callbacks/onClicks)